# getLayout()->createBlock()->setdata() not passing variables

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, controllers

Im trying to pass information from my controller to the template.

My Controller:

```
    $response= "test"; (variable that I want to pass to PHTML)

    $this->loadLayout( array('default','path_to_test_phtml'));

    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('block_name')
        ->setData('response', $response)
        ->setTemplate('path_to_test.phtml');
    $block->setResponse($response); //magic method
    $this->renderLayout();
```

My Block:

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

My Template:

```
<?php
$response = $this->getResponse();
?>
<?php echo $this->response; ?>
```

My Layout:

```
<path_to_test_phtml>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="block/name" name="track_bynumber" template="path_to_test_phtml.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</path_to_test_phtml>
```

No information "test" appear in the template.. any help appreciated. brgds

Answer (score 4):

```
$response = 'value'; //dynamic value to pass in block   

Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('blockname')
    ->setData('area','frontend')
    ->setTemplate('templatepath')
    ->setResponse($response)
    ->toHtml();
```

Comment: what is the idea to use ->toHtml();? brgds

Comment: -for output of block

Comment: $this->renderLayout(); ??

Comment: +1; I needed to get the `Mage::app()->getLayout()` part outside of a template context. Worked perfectly to load a CMS block. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`createBlock` creates an new instance of your block.
After that it seams you do nothing to it.
`renderLayout` just renders the blocks instantiated through `loadLayout`.

I assume you also have an instance of your block declared in the layout files somewhere.

In this case, try:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('block name here')->setResponse($response)....;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Following your advice I edited the file and now prints "Array" in PHTML instead of "Test"

Comment: at least you are getting something now.