# creating a block from a different module, setting attribute code variable

Tags: module, attributes, blocks

I am calling a block

```
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Amasty_Shopby_Block_List')
```

that has this in its default method

```
 $attribute  = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
            ->loadByCode($entityTypeId, $this->getAttributeCode());
```

I need to set the block so that `getAttributeCode` returns 'manufacturer' adding

```
->setAttribute('manufacturer')
```

is not working any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `->setAttribute('manufacturer')` use `->setAttributeCode('manufacturer')`
Just make sure the method `getAttributeCode` does not exist.

Comment: i tried that too it does not work

Comment: what does it mean to make sure getAttributeCode  doesnt exsist?

Comment: If a method does not exist, then it will be transformed automatically to `getData('attribute_code')`.

Comment: i am trying `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Amasty_Shopby_Block_List')->setData('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');` and it still is not working?

Comment: why does the attribute code not get set? `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Amasty_Shopby_Block_List')->setAttributeCode('manufacturer')`

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar post where setData does not work. Here is the link:-[ref link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31101/getlayout-createblock-setdata-not-passing-variables).

May be this can help you as you have mentioned in comment that below code is not working.
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Amasty_Shopby_Block_List')->setData('attribute‌​_code', 'manufacturer');